# Rails: pagy ignores attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

I need to show attr_accessor value on index page. for pagination I'm using pagy gem. Below is the code block:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @posts.map do |post|
      post_info = get_post_info(post.url)
      post.update_attribute(:icon, post_info["icon"])
      post.update_attribute(:subtitle, post_info["subtitle"])
    end
    print @posts[0].icon
    @pagy, @posts = pagy(@posts)    
  end
```

printing icon of first post gives the correct url in controller.

When I use `post.icon` in view file, its nil. If I send @posts directly without pagy, it works as expected. How to solve this?

Here is the code without pagy

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @posts.map do |post|
      post_info = get_post_info(post.url)
      post.update_attribute(:icon, post_info["icon"])
      post.update_attribute(:subtitle, post_info["subtitle"])
    end
  end
```

Here is my view code:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="">
      <%= render partial: "posts/index", collection: @posts, as: :post %>
  </div>
```

**_index.html.erb as below**

```
  <div class="flex mb-4">
    <div class="rounded float-left mr-3 my-3" style=";">
      <% if !post.icon.nil? %>
        <%= image_tag post.icon, class: "app-icon float-right w-full h-full rounded-3xl", style: "width: 150px;" %>
      <% else %>
         <%= image_tag 'post.svg', class: "app-icon w-full h-full", style: "width: 150px;" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 85%" class="mt-5 pt-3 lg:ml-4">
      <h3 class="lg:text-xl text-sm font-semibold text-gray-50"><%= post.title %></h3>
      <div class="lg:text-base text-xs text-gray-50"> <%= post.subtitle %> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add the code that works (without pagy) to your question.

Comment: Updated question with code block

Comment: Wow, ok, that's very weird. Sorry, no thoughts on how that could be happening.

Comment: Note that each call to `update_attribute` does an update query and does not validate and does not raise an error if there's a problem, so it's possible `post.update_attribute(:icon, post_info["icon"])` is simply failing. `post.update!(icon: post_info["icon], subtitle: post_info["subtitle"])` validates and does it in one query and will raise on error. You should also avoid `Post.all` which loads every row in the table into memory and instead consider [`Post.find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each).

Comment: @Schwern tried this. still getting the same. in controller, able to access the attr_accessor. but in view file, it is nil

Comment: @Beu Can we see your view code? And how are you verifying .icon and .subtitle in the controller?

Comment: @SchwernEdited question with view file content and print in controller

Comment: Is the value of `@posts[0].icon` what you expect if you call `print @posts[0].icon` again immediately after `@pagy, @posts = pagy(@posts)` but before the end of `index`?

Comment: before `@pagy, @posts = pagy(@posts` it gives icon url and after `@pagy` its nil

Comment: Nice, so the issue isn't the view file. `pagy(...)` doesn't do much more than [`collection.offset(...).limit(...)`](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy/blob/6.4.3/lib/pagy/backend.rb#L35) when updating the relation so what about replacing `@pagy, @posts = pagy(@posts)` with various invocations of `@posts = @posts.offset(...).limit(...)`, then checking whether the `icon` attribute is still `nil` before the end of `index`?

Comment: @msbit yes, attr_accessor is nil if I do `@posts = @posts.offset(10)`. before offset it prints the url and after offset, its nil

Comment: So it feels like it's neither the view, nor pagy that's at fault here. It does seem like the `update_attribute` calls aren't saving correctly, have you confirmed the database looks the way you expect by running queries on it outside of Rails?

Comment: here, icon is attr_accessor

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that's as far as I can go. If you wanted to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the same behaviour (with _all_ code required for someone else to run it) then we could likely debug further.